# Firebase function deployed is not showing up in functions dashboard

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I can not get my Firebase function to deploy.

Here is the function code:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.newTrxn = functions.firestore
    .document("company/{companyId}/trxns")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: String(snapshot.title),
          body: String(snapshot.body),
        },
        topic: context.params.companyId,
      };
      return admin.messaging().send(payload);
    });
```

Here is the output of the firebase deploy command:

```
PS C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence> firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'deal-diligence-5de73'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8313

i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\functions (75.87 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function newTrxn(us-central1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 18 (1st Gen) function myFunction(us-central1)...
!  functions: failed to create function projects/deal-diligence-5de73/locations/us-central1/functions/newTrxn
Failed to create function projects/deal-diligence-5de73/locations/us-central1/functions/newTrxn
```

Why is this failing to deploy?

UPDATE:
Here is the log from console.google.com

I don't see any error messages in this. Where would I look for error messages or how do I debug this function?

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 3,
      "message": "The request has errors"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {
      "principalEmail": "",
      "principalSubject": "user:"
    },
    "requestMetadata": {
      "callerIp": "",
      "callerSuppliedUserAgent": "FirebaseCLI/12.9.1,gzip(gfe),gzip(gfe)",
      "requestAttributes": {
        "time": "2023-11-23T22:19:39.268854Z",
        "auth": {}
      },
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "projects/deal-diligence-5de73/locations/us-central1/functions/newTrxnNotification",
        "permission": "cloudfunctions.functions.create",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/deal-diligence-5de73/locations/us-central1/functions/newTrxnNotification",
    "request": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.functions.v1.CreateFunctionRequest",
      "function": {
        "sourceUploadUrl": "https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-606679065147.us-central1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/f21830a3-53e7-4e27-80fe-b5d1a8ab577c.zip?GoogleAccessId=service-394692266013@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1700779778&Signature=byu3MnzRX3LKhRX12qnwtbqCxac8c%2BGxuJcaqSM7tRkmR3H0gN1Ou5QGWTJ3QNQ5WvMTJX2o34DLPcqPiuKXkmnFd8u6%2B93FxeU9tUhhUFax%2F8SZ143zj25jftBHAgI0uLZ6Nk6crCbgunZrj5ZczQ6x9t%2B5cvPsHmZNJc9GGvC0EbaPBTsSF7hcsgSuTpGQnCJcI8ClfvAZvovPjJv1adSN3xusbj%2BhbMjBS5a8Tbkg8Ht4EsiTSnMkTNPEkhj8V6yvtPG1iQGMrI6r9t%2FVsFa4q3v8zkFGMOvyMXElsKfceI%2Ff24KQMVhBYAiwgo4d7zU1%2F8hJakeBwEgGA%2BWU7Q%3D%3D",
        "dockerRegistry": "ARTIFACT_REGISTRY",
        "name": "projects/deal-diligence-5de73/locations/us-central1/functions/newTrxnNotification",
        "labels": {
          "deployment-tool": "cli-firebase",
          "firebase-functions-hash": ""
        },
        "runtime": "nodejs18",
        "eventTrigger": {
          "eventType": "providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create",
          "resource": "projects/deal-diligence-5de73/databases/(default)/documents/company/{companyId}/trxns"
        },
        "entryPoint": "newTrxnNotification"
      },
      "location": "projects/deal-diligence-5de73/locations/us-central1"
    },
    "resourceLocation": {
      "currentLocations": [
        "us-central1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "insertId": "5a8sc9dopbz",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "deal-diligence-5de73",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "function_name": "newTrxnNotification"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-11-23T22:19:39.208293Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/deal-diligence-5de73/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-11-23T22:19:39.894163362Z"
}
```

Comment: you can see functions build logs on https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds (and select region) if build had started.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the audit logs from google. I don't know if that helps.